# Difference between using Generic and Protocol as type parameters, what are the pros and cons of implement them in a function

Tags: swift, generics, parameters, protocols

Since Swift allows us using both Protocol and Generic as parameter types in a function, the scenario below has come into my mind:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var name: String{ get }
}

class ClassA: AProtocol {
    var name = "Allen"
}

func printNameGeneric<T: AProtocol>(param: T) {
    print(param.name)
}

func printNameProtocol(param: AProtocol) {
    print(param.name)
}
```

The first function uses generic as parameter type with a type constraint, and the second function uses protocol as the parameter type directly. However, these two functions can have the same effect, which is the point confusing me. So my questions are:

1. What are the specific scenarios for each of them (or a case which can only be done by the specific one, but not another)?
2. For the given case, both functions turn out the same result. Which one is better to implement (or the pros and cons of each of them)?

[This great talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) has mentioned **generic specialization**, which is a optimization that turn the way of function dispatching from **dynamic dispatching** (function with **non-generic parameters)** to **static dispatching** or **inlining** (function with **generic parameters)**. Since **static dispatching** and **inlining** are less expensive in contrast with **dynamic dispatching**, to implement functions with generic can always provide a better performance.

@Hamish also gave great information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446487/what-is-the-in-practice-difference-between-generic-and-protocol-typed-function-p), have a look for more information.

Here is a new question came to me:

```
struct StructA: AProtocol {
    var a: Int
}

struct StructB: AProtocol {
    var b: Int
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    var aVar: AProtocol

    if sender == self.buttonA
    {
        aVar = StructA(a: 1)
    }
    else if sender == self.buttonA
    {
        aVar = StructB(b: 2)
    }

    foo(param: aVar)
}

func foo<T: AProtocol>(param: T) {
    //do something
}
```

3. If there are several types conform to a Protocol, and are pass in to a generic function in different conditions dynamically. As shown above, pressing different buttons will pass different types(StructA or StructB) of parameter into function, would the generic specialization still work in this case?

Comment: Strongly related (dupe?): [What is the in-practice difference between these two Swift functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446487/what-is-the-in-practice-difference-between-these-two-swift-functions)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @Hamish, the previous post has given a scenario for using generic type, which makes me more clear (Generic gives more power on type constraints)! But I'd like to know more in detail, besides type constraints, are there other pros & cons of using generic and protocol, or the only difference between them is about type constraints.

Comment: [I went ahead and wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41490551/2976878) (what I hope is a complete) answer to the linked Q&A (I had been meaning to for the last few months but never really got round to it). Given how similar the questions are, may want to consider flagging this question to be merged with the linked one to transfer the 2 existing answers here over to the linked Q&A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the in-practice difference between generic and protocol-typed function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446487/what-is-the-in-practice-difference-between-generic-and-protocol-typed-function-p)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is actually a video from this year's WWDC about that (it was about performance of classes, structs and protocols; I don't have a link but you should be able to find it).

In your second function, where you pass a any value that conforms to that protocol, you are actually passing a container that has 24 bytes of storage for the passed value, and 16 bytes for type related information (to determine which methods to call, ergo dynamic dispatch). If the passed value is now bigger than 24 bytes in memory, the object will be allocated on the heap and the container stores a reference to that object! That is actually extremely time consuming and should certainly be avoided if possible.

In your first function, where you use a generic constraint, there is actually created another function by the compiler that explicitly performs the function's operations upon that type. (If you use this function with lots of different types, your code size may, however, increase significantly; see C++ code bloat for further reference.) However, the compiler can now statically dispatch the methods, inline the function if possible and does certainly not have to allocate any heap space. Stated in the video mentioned above, code size does not have to increase significantly as code can still be shared... so the function with generic constraint is certainly the way to go!

Comment: a big thank to you. You really provided a good explanation and useful information, [this great talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) has covered about my question in detail, which has mentioned about generic specialization (this is the meat).

Comment: this is very confusing, so the only practical difference here is performance? in C++ templates and abstracdt types are COMPLETELY different, it's not just about performance, so the distinction between a template and a function that takes an abstract type is much, much clearer - it's not just about PERFORMANCE.

Answer (score -1):

Now we have two `protocol` below:

```
protocol A {
    func sometingA()
}
protocol B {
    func sometingB()
}
```

Then the parameter need to conform to both `A` and `B`.

```
//Generic solution
func methodGeneric<T:A>(t:T)where T:B {
    t.sometingA()
    t.sometingB()
}
//we need protocol C to define the parameter type
protocol C:A,B {}
//Protocol solution
func methodProtocol(c:C){
    c.sometingA()
    c.sometingB()
}
```

It seems that nothing is wrong but when we define a struct like this:

```
struct S:A,B {
    func sometingB() {
        print("B")
    }

    func sometingA() {
        print("A")
    }
}
```

The `methodGeneric` works but we need to change `struct S:A,B` to `struct S:C` to make `methodProtocol` work. Some questions:

1. Do we really need `protocol C`?
2. Why not would we write like `func method(s:S)`?

You could read more about this in the [Generic Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) for additional information .