# Not calling right method when wrapped into a function with no specific generic type

Tags: swift, generics

Sample code which I am experimenting in playground

```
protocol Shape {
    init()
}

class Circle: Shape {
    required init() {
    }
}

class Square: Shape {
    required init() {
    }
}

class ShapeMapping<T> {
    func map() -> T? {
        print("Any shape called")
        return nil
    }
}

extension ShapeMapping where T: Shape {
    func map() -> T? {
        print("Shape type called")
        return T.self()
    }
}

extension ShapeMapping where T: Square {
    func map() -> T? {
        print("Square type called")
        return Square() as? T
    }
}

class ShapeWrapper<T> {
    func determineShape() -> T?  {
        return ShapeMapping<T>().map()
    }

}
```

Code works correctly and calls expected method for type Square when I call

```
let square: Square? = ShapeMapping<Square>().map()

Output: Square type called
```

But, when I call a wrapper method and pass Square type output is different

```
let mappingSquareShape: Square? = ShapeWrapper<Square>().determineShape()

Actual: Any shape called
Expected: Square type called
```

Is type information does not get passed from ShapeWrapper to ShapeMapping? Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: extensions can't define overrides like this.

Comment: As per apple docs nothing wrong when explicitly specifying type with extension https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID553

Comment: No there's nothing wrong with it, it just won't have the polymorphic behaviour youre looking for

Comment: Compare [Wrong specialized generic function gets called in Swift 3 from an indirect call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41980001/2976878). Inside `determineShape()`, the compiler doesn't know anything about the type of `T` – it could be an arbitrary type. Therefore the only overload of `map()` it can dispatch to is the unconstrained one on `ShapeMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I found "func map()" will be ambiguous when i define the class ShapeMapping(), The compiler will not know which one to use, maybe you can change the method name in the extension

```
extension ShapeMapping where T: Shape{
  func test() -> T? {
    print("Shape type called")
    return nil
  }
}
```