# Swift function overloading - invoking func with specific parameter (in place of Any parameter) on passing Any object

Tags: swift, overloading, swift-mirror

I have 3 structs:

```
struct Address: Codable {
    var addressLine1: String
}
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
}
struct Order: Codable {
    var person: Person?
    var address: Address?
}
```

In my ViewController class I am using Mirror to access each of the properties within Order:

```
let address = Address(addressLine1: "Some unknown address")
let person = Person(name: "Some unknown name")
let order = Order(person: person, address: address)

let newOrderMirror = Mirror(reflecting: order)
newOrderMirror.children.forEach {
    display(child: $0.value)
}
```

In ViewController I have implemented 3 display functions:

```
func display(child: Any) {
    // this should never get called
    print(child)
}

func display(child: Person) {
    print(child)
}

func display(child: Address) {
    print(child)
}
```

In above case it is always invoking `func display(child: Any)`, however I want it to invoke the functions with specific parameter. **Is there any way to achieve this without type casting?**:

Off-course this will work:

```
    newOrderMirror.children.forEach {
        if let bs = $0.value as? Person {
            display(child: bs)
        } else if let addr = $0.value as? Address {
            display(child: addr)
        }
        display(child: $0.value)
    }
```

Is there any other elegant way to achieve the desired behavior without using `if-let + typecasting`?

**Update 1:**

Found something related over here - [How to call the more specific method of overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41531569/217586)

**Update 2:**

I can achieve a more concise solution by following these steps:

1. Declare Displayable protocol with func display()
2. Let each Modelimplement this protocol
3. Within forEach on each children I can just bind and typecast to the protocol and invoke display method on it

However this looks like an ugly solution to me as Model is now serving 2 responsibilities - i. Handle/ Store data, ii. Handle how the data is displayed. The 2nd responsibility looks to me like more reasonable for a controller or presenter class to implement rather than the model class, hence I want to avoid that path

Comment: Mirror.Child.value is defined as being of type Any so I don't understand how you expect to get around doing a cast?

Comment: Here is something similar achieved over here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41531569/217586, hence I asked a specific query.

Comment: I am not sure how this question relates to using generics.

Answer (score 1):

The `children` property points to a collection of [Mirror.Child](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror/child) elements, which is actually a tuple made of a `String` and an `Any`. Thus every child of a mirror has the compile type set to `Any` (this is needed as the mirror can virtually be applied to any type).

Due to the above, and given the fact that overloading is a compile-time feature, results that the compiler can't pick other overload than the one with the `Any` parameter.

One workaround you could make to this is to change the body of the first `display()` overload:

```swift
func display(child: Any) {
    switch child {
    case let person as Person: display(person)
    case let address as Address: display(address)
    default: print(child)
    }
}

func display(child: Person) {
    print(child)
}

func display(child: Address) {
    print(child)
}
```

Basically you still need to help the compiler pick the right function to call.