# Gratuitous Use of Generics

Tags: swift, generics

I'm staring at an ex-colleague's code (on an Extension) that looks like this:

```
func set<Object: SomeProtocol>(object value: Object) {
```

What advantages does the signature with generics bring compared to the plain old version?

```
func set(object value: SomeProtocol) {
```

Comment: Compare [What is the in-practice difference between generic and protocol-typed function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38446487/2976878)

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, voted up the question and your answer there, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As a pattern, your ex-colleague's version is more flexible, because it should work with any type of protocol. Protocols with associated types, for instance, will not work with your version:

```
// error: protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
func foo(bar: Equatable) {}
```

Comment: Very interesting, so you can do `func foo<T: Equatable>(bar: T) {}` without compilation issues. Hmmm...